# createAction with required payload

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

Can you provide example how to create action with required payload?

for example if i create like this

`const foo = createAction<{ email: string }>('some_type');`

type of **foo()** equals to `ActionCreatorWithOptionalPayload`
How to get it with `ActionCreatorWithPayload`?

gh issue link: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/834

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeating my answer over here in case other people read this:

I'm 99% sure you're using TypeScript with `strictNullChecks: false` in your `tsconfig.json`.

That means that your code up there is handled by TypeScript like `const foo = createAction<{ email: string } | null | undefined>('some_type');` - and that `undefined` is interpreted by RTK as "this is optional".

Every type definition you do will always be `| null | undefined` internally if you have `strictNullChecks: false`. If you don't believe me, try code like `const x: number = null` or `const y: number = undefined`. This is really not how TS is meant to be used, but just a "backwards-compatibility" feature for TS pre-2.3.

Other than you enabling strict mode for your TypeScript config, there is unfortunately not much we can do about it.